# Does Java's regular expression engine optimizes character class expressions internally?

Tags: java, regex, performance, optimization

We know we can come up with complex character classes such as:

```
[A-F&&[^B]]     // A through F, excluding B
[G-L&&[^H]]     // G through L, excluding H
```

We can do intersections && and unions (implicitly done):

```
[[A-F&&[^B]][G-L&&[^H]]]      // union of both classes above
```

But the question is, will Java internally generate an optimized automaton so that the expression above is reduced to something like a simplified expression:

```
[A-L&&[^BH]]  // union of both classes above, simplified
```

or not necessarily? I just want to determine whether it is worth coming up with some regular expression simplification routine to improve matching performance or whether Java is already doing simplification of character classes implicitly.

Comment: I took a JMH benchmark and it's inconclusive; the latter is faster, but not much (2% to 7% faster in different cases).  Looking at `Pattern#compile`, there is some optimization present, but probably not as much as you're planning.

Comment: Basically, character classes are always compiled into a "microprogram" by the regex egnine, that is why they are faster than capturing groups with alternations. However, what you ask for can only be checked with some real test. Just perform a search on a string some 50-100K times and measure the time it took, and you will get your results.

Comment: Another approach would be to read the code. Depending on the version of java and your companies policies, this would tell you. Of course, the implementation could change.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the OpenJDK 12 source code, the [`clazz` method](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/regex/Pattern.java#l2614) is where character classes are parsed.

The line of code where the intersection is done is [here](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/regex/Pattern.java#l2673):

```
prev = prev.and(curr);
```

Which is defined [here](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/regex/Pattern.java#l5664):

```
default CharPredicate and(CharPredicate p) {
    return ch -> is(ch) && p.is(ch);
}
```

As you can see, it's an implementation with a simple "and". There's no code that later merges/simplifies those predicates either.

So the answer is: **No**, it doesn't optimize them.

You can also verify that by debugging through the regex code. You might have to step through a bit of code but eventually you should end up in that `and` implementation.